# Pandas convert minute number index (0 to 1440) to datetime

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, strftime

I have a DataFrame, `P`, in the format:

```
                0             1             2
0    10088.245329   9905.462496  12328.830197
1    10092.783624   9688.034026  11785.442316
2    10312.043154   9501.677065  11784.126068
3    10314.919339   9694.886693  11419.465596
...
1438  9636.005396   9544.771643  14181.272599
1439  9414.292352   9312.184926  13988.822708
```

The index represents the minute of the day.

I would like to reformat this to a datatime object so that I can `resample` the data into half hourly bins.

I have been playing with the `to_datetime` function to do this:

```
P.index=pd.to_datetime(P.index,format='%M')
```

This works to get minutes but not the correct hour:

```
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[1900-01-01 00:00:00, ..., 1900-01-01 00:59:00]
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

**EDIT:**

I Managed to do it:

```
pd.to_datetime([(str(int(x))+' '+str(y)) for x,y in zip(np.floor(P.index/60),P.index%60)],format='%H %M')
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[1900-01-01 00:00:00, ..., 1900-01-01 23:59:00]
Length: 1440, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

I have a feeling that there is a better way though??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where I put `np.arange(1480)` you can use `P.index`

In >= 0.15.0/master (coming in early Oct 2014)

```
In [5]: pd.Timestamp('20130101') + pd.to_timedelta(np.arange(1480),unit='m')
Out[5]: 
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2013-01-01 00:00:00, ..., 2013-01-02 00:39:00]
Length: 1480, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

Works in all versions

```
In [4]: pd.DatetimeIndex((pd.Timestamp('20130101') + pd.to_timedelta(np.arange(1480),unit='m')).values)

Out[4]: 
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2013-01-01 00:00:00, ..., 2013-01-02 00:39:00]
Length: 1480, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

Just for interest, here is a timedelta resample in action:

```
In [4]: pd.set_option('max_rows',10)

In [5]: df = DataFrame({'A' : np.arange(1480)},index=pd.to_timedelta(np.arange(1480),unit='T'))

In [6]: df
Out[6]: 
                    A
0 days 00:00:00     0
0 days 00:01:00     1
0 days 00:02:00     2
0 days 00:03:00     3
0 days 00:04:00     4
...               ...
1 days 00:35:00  1475
1 days 00:36:00  1476
1 days 00:37:00  1477
1 days 00:38:00  1478
1 days 00:39:00  1479

[1480 rows x 1 columns]

In [7]: df.resample('30T',how='sum')
Out[7]: 
                     A
0 days 00:00:00    435
0 days 00:30:00   1335
0 days 01:00:00   2235
0 days 01:30:00   3135
0 days 02:00:00   4035
...                ...
0 days 22:30:00  40935
0 days 23:00:00  41835
0 days 23:30:00  42735
1 days 00:00:00  43635
1 days 00:30:00  14745

[50 rows x 1 columns]
```